# Objective C - Table View: load items from database

Tags: objective-c, database, uitableview, dynamic

I have a table view and until now I fill the table with spelled numbers like this:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)data {
    if(!_data){
        _data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        // spelled numbers 
        NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle;
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
            NSNumber *thisNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i];
            NSString *spelledOutNumber = [formatter stringFromNumber:thisNumber];
            [_data addObject:spelledOutNumber];
        }
    }
    return _data;
}
```

But how can I fill the table now with dynamic items from a database?

This is how I get the data from database:

```
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.example.net/iOS/game/getData.php"];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){

        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
        NSString *errorCode = [json valueForKey:@"error"];

        if([errorCode isEqualToString:@"e0"]){

            NSArray *jsondata = [json objectForKey:@"data"];

            for (int i = 0; i < [jsondata count]; i++) {
                NSString *name = [[jsondata objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"name"];
                [_data addObject:name];
            }

        }

    }];

    [dataTask resume];
```

But how can I load this data now to the table view? If I just put the database code to the data method it doesnt work, because the database code is asynchron. Can someone help me with it?

**Edit:**

Here are the data methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.data count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: pls show ur cellForRow method. Once the data fetch is completed, call the reloadData for your table view.

Comment: are you use variable "_data" in tableview  "numberOfRowsInSection"

Comment: if you use the _data varaible in cellRowIndexPath. Just you can reload the tableview '[tableview reload];" for (int i = 0; i < [jsondata count]; i++) {
                NSString *name = [[jsondata objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"name"];
                [_data addObject:name];   //here you will reload the tableview
            }

Comment: With what must I replace your "tableview"? I mean '[??? reload];' **EDIT:** Got it: self.tableView